# Can we create a dynamic sized TrueCrypt container on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, truecrypt

Is it possible to create a dynamic [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) container on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

No. According to [the documentation](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=creating-new-volume), dynamic TrueCrypt containers use pre-allocated NTFS sparse files.

> Note that sparse files can only be created in the NTFS file system.

In the OS X version of TrueCrypt, you can only create *Mac OS Extended* and *FAT* containers.

---

The only quick and easy alternative to TrueCrypt containers consists in creating an encrypted sparse disk image through Disk Utility:

[image]

You will then be asked for a password:

[image]

Comment: What if we installed some sort of NTFS write support on the Mac system? Might TC then be able to create the dynamic NTFS container?

Comment: I highly doubt TrueCrypt would be aware of that. You could try and create the container on Windows, then see if you can write to it using various NTFS tools for OS X.